# OpenGL Ubuntu 13.10 QtCreator - undefined reference to `glutMainLoop`

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, ubuntu

If I try to execute the code from [here, the OpenGLBook](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/), I get this error messages:

```
undefined reference to glutMainLoop
undefined reference to glGetString
undefined reference to glClearColor
```

and so on ... I installed the following packages:

`libglew-dev`, `liblglew1.8`, `freeglut3-dev` and `freeglut3`.

I am running on Ubuntu 13.10 with Qt Creator v3.0.0.

My `.pro` file looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Build step for debugging is `qmake Project.pro -r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG += debug`

How can I fix my project?

Comment: It's not enough to only install the development packages, you also have to link with the actual libraries.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Qt `pro` files enough to say, but I'm sure you can find out easily with the help of the search engine of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to change my `pro` file to

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

# this is the important part
unix|win32: LIBS += -lGLU
unix|win32: LIBS += -lGL
unix|win32: LIBS += -lglut
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to c++ !
You are using a library (freeglut I gather) and for this you need 2 things :

1) include the headers (*.h file(s)) that declare the functions/classes/methods that you need

2) your program needs to link with the actual shared library (.so files in Linux)

In your .pro file you need to specify the path to the libraries you want to link with. Add this :

LIBS += -lglut

It means add the library glut to the list of libraries to link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as you may have seen, I already figured it out.