# OpenGL Ubuntu 12.04 QtCreator - undefined reference to `__glewTexImage3D'

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, qt-creator

I try to run the code from the website.It can work in Win7,but it have error in Ubuntu.

```
error: undefined reference to `__glewTexImage3D'
```

I fixed some error refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509367/opengl-ubuntu-13-10-qtcreator-undefined-reference-to-glutmainloop) but still got error in glew related.I downloaded glew module and add `unix: LIBS += -lglew` to pro file.but got `error: cannot find -lglew` Can someone tell me how to deal with glew.lib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the line below.Before this,I download glew in Linux,and `make` I got some libGLEW.a file.Then I can add this line.Problem solved

```
 LIBS += -L/path/to/glew-1.11.0/lib -lGLEW
```